# I have elements that move on my page, when they do, the outlines flicker. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: html, css

Any idea why it's happening? I appreciate any and all help. I'm new to html and css so maybe im making a simple mistake here.

I have several columns that move up and down with images loaded locally into the columns. The images shuffle every 6 minutes. The outline around the images flickers as they move up and down the screen. The issue goes away if I remove the outline. I have no idea whats going on.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
html {
height: 100vh;
height:100%
overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  scroll: no;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
.main {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 50vw;
  background: #333;
}
 
.main img {
  border-radius: 6px;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  ##filter: blur(0.03rem);
  opacity: .75;
  outline-offset: -3px;
  padding: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;

}
 
 
.main:hover img {
##filter: blur(0.03rem);
opacity: .75;
transition: all 10s;
}
 
.main img:hover {
  
  ##filter: blur(0);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .2s
  
}
 

.main .single-column {
 -webkit-animation: var(--animation, none) 360s linear 0.01s infinite;
}
 
.main .single-column:hover {
 animation-play-state: paused;
}
 
.main .single-column:nth-of-type(odd) {
  vertical-align:top;
align-self: flex-end;
  --direction: 15%;
}


@keyframes slide {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(var(--direction, -15%));

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your code so that we can see what’s wrong.

Comment: @JongwooLee I updated the post with my css. Thanks for letting me know I could do that.

Comment: The CSS alone will not help others determine the issue or reproduce it for themselves. The HTML is needed to do that and whether content is generated dynamically by Javascript etc.

Comment: This link should help you put a working snippet into your question so we can help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You might like to put your CSS through a validator as there are several errors.